# Could liquid hydrogen tank be any shape we want?

Tags: pressure, hydrogen, liquid-state

I am doing the initial design of an aircraft for my Aerospace Engineering project. I want to use liquid hydrogen as the fuel of my aircraft. However, a cylindrical fuel tank or spherical fuel tank would waste a lot of space. So I am thinking, could we have liquid hydrogen tank of shapes other than these two? Can we have a liquid hydrogen tank with the cross-section of an eclipse? Or a rectangle with rounded corner?

Answer (score 2):

The best pressure tanks are spherical, because deviations from sphericality introduce high stress distributions whose magnitudes are difficult to predict. This is especially true with rectangles or squares which is why you never see them in use for pressure vessels.

Cylindrical tanks are easier to analyze than rectangular tanks and have been used for years where more space-filling capacity is needed, but for applications like this the ends of the cylinder are always hemispherical. With reinforcing hoop ribs encircling the inside or outside of the cylindrical tank with hemispherical caps, the stress distributions at the join between the hemispheres and the cylinder can be analyzed and managed.